# prevent duplicate site / page / layouts / templates / webparts, possible

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We have a sharepoint environment with many sites (and sometimes many site collections). Each site (or site collection) has the same default page with some custom webparts that use sitecolumn values (for example a projectcode or clientcode) to show information from external systems. (for each project we have to create a separate site (or site collection) because of other reasons)

What is the best approach to minimize duplication? The dynamic parts of the page are stored in site columns. When we add a new webpart, ideally the default page every site/page should show the new webpart without spreading the update to the individual pages

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach you may want to take is to use the web part as a wrapper for a user control.  The user control does the heavy lifting on the site.  Once the web part is included on your pages, the user control should be able to tell which site it is being executed on and pull the necessary dynamic data from your site columns.

When you need to make updates, you update the user control and then redeploy the solution package to the farm.  Each site will pick up the change as soon as the solution is deployed.

Here is a little information about this approach:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649867.aspx.

The above article relates to WSS 3.0, but that should give you a starting point.

An approach you may want to look at for SharePoint 2010 is a visual web part.  More info can be found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597539.aspx.

Comment: Basically you are saying that the best option to nest webparts/usercontrols. Using a page-layout/page-template/ ?? is no option?

Comment: If your requirement is that you need to be able to add a web part to a page without affecting the layout of other pages on other sites, then yes, I would go with a custom web part using the user control method I mentioned.  It is possible to develop a page layout to do what you want, but I think you would still end up having to develop some kind of a control to pull in the dynamic data you want (based on which site you are on).  Largely just depends on the scope of your requirements.